# VBA excel equation that continues down the column

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, sum, equation

I am trying to write an equation that varies down the column, the general equation is the same.

I.e. There is Column A, B and C, with the equation displaying results in Column C.
The general equation = C1(an initial result)+(B3+B1)/2 *(A3-A1) which would update on the next row to

=C2+(B4+B2)/2*(A4-A1) and so on as you go down the column

On top of this I have included * to be displayed in Column C when there are no values in column A, the code I have written so far is displayed below, I really hope some one can help me thanks

```
''''row number = row number + 1 on a loop
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(19, 1) = 0 '''this is A1=0
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(19, 3) = 0 '''This is C1 = 0
If Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(19 + row_number, 1) = "" Then 
''''if cell in A column is blank show * in column C
Usui_wear_depth = "*"
Else: Usui_wear_depth = Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(Sheet3.[C22] + (([B25] + [B22]) / 2) *
([A25] - [A21])) ''' this is the General equation
End If
Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(19 + row_number, 6) = Usui_wear_depth
```

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be done as a single formula, no need for VBA:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A3),"*",C1+(B3+B1)/2*(A3-$A$1))
```

If you simply copy this formula down the cells of column C, it will change as you described.

I made the reference to A1 an absolute reference, since it was the only one in your equation that didn't change from the first version to the second. You may also decide which cell in Column A should be checked to show '*' - I wasn't clear on that from your question. Hope this helps!